# Error: "The resource cannot be found" when trying to pass in an empty object to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ProjectDetailsViewModel that has a Project object in it. I want to make only one View for the Update form and for the Insert Form. In other words, if the server does not return a project to the View, then the form should be empty and if a project gets returned to the view, then the values should be filled in and the user can change or add... 
The question is how do I return a null project to the View when I click the "Add Project" button? I have to return a projectId to the View...
This is what I tried so far but I keep on getting the error:"The resource cannot be found." Thanks.

This is the ProjectDetailsView:

```
@using DCMS.Models.Projects
@model DCMS.Models.Projects.DataViewModels.ProjectDetailsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Project Details";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateProjectView", "Project", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @*<div class="errormessage">@Html.ValidationSummary(false)</div>*@
    if (Model.ReturnMessage != null || Model.ReturnMessage != "")
    {
        <div class="InfoMessageOuter">
            <div class="InfoMessageMiddle">
                <div class="InfoMessageInner">@Model.ReturnMessage</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Project.ClientId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Project.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Project.ModeledOn)
    <br/>
    @*<h2 style="font-size: 20px; margin: 5px;">@Model.Project.Client.ClientName </h2>*@

    <div>
    <table style="margin: 0 30px;">
```

This is the Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
     public ActionResult GetProjectView(string returnMessage, int? id = null)
                {
                    ProjectDetailsViewModel projectDetails;
                    if (id == null)
                    {
                        projectDetails = new ProjectDetailsViewModel();
                        return View("ProjectView",projectDetails);
                    }
                    projectDetails = ProjectDataAccess.GetProjectDetails(id.Value);
                    if (projectDetails == null) return PartialView("Error");
                    projectDetails.ReturnMessage = returnMessage;

                    return View("ProjectView", projectDetails);
                }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateProjectView(ProjectDetailsViewModel projectViewModel)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                projectViewModel.ReturnMessage = @"Error! Update Failed.";
                return GetProjectView(projectViewModel.ReturnMessage, projectViewModel.Project.Id);
            }
            if (projectViewModel.Project.Id != null)
            {
                var success = ProjectDataAccess.UpdateProject(projectViewModel.Project);
                projectViewModel.ReturnMessage = success ? @"Project Updated Successfully" : @"Error! Update Failed";
            }
            else if(projectViewModel.Project.Id == null)
            {
                var success = ProjectDataAccess.AddProject(projectViewModel.Project);
                projectViewModel.ReturnMessage = success ? @"Project Added Successfully" : @"Error! Insert Failed";
            }
            return GetProjectView(projectViewModel.ReturnMessage, projectViewModel.Project.Id);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `RedirectToAction` like this

```
return RedirectToAction("GetProjectView", new{returnMessage=projectViewModel.ReturnMessage,id = projectViewModel.Project.Id});
```

because when you use `return GetProjectView` it will return to the same action `UpdateProjectView` but if you use `RedirectToAction` it will go to `GetProjectView` action and it will return the `view` instead of going back to `UpdateProjectView` action. you can also check this [Controller.RedirectToAction Method (String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_3)

Comment: :thanks for answering, but "GetProjectView" is the name of an ActionResult method so when I return that function , It goes to that function and automatically return that view... Anyways, the problem is before that- by the GET method. How can I return an empty project to the View so it gives me an empty form? The point is that I want to have one View for Updates and Inserts....

Comment: @BYG did you try RedirectToAction ? because it will load ProjectView when id is null

Comment: yes I tried and I still get the error "The resource cannot be found."

Comment: @BYG it looks like ProjectView is not found are you sure its in the same name of folder of controller?

Comment: @BYG did you add any new route in route table?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I checked. Also, if it wouldn't of been in the same folder then it will be underlined red.

Comment: and when you go to controller/GetProjectView it displays GetProjectView ?

Comment: yes, only when you pass in a projectId and that's the problem here that when I want the View to return empty,  it doesn't find it.

Comment: @BYG and try `return View("ProjectView");`